# Export gridview to Excel only saves column b row 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I've been using the same code on several web apps for exporting gridview data to excel. Normally works fine but in this case, when I open the generated excel file there is only one cell populated. This is my export code:

```
protected void export_btn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ExportGridToExcel();
}
private void ExportGridToExcel()  
{  
    Response.Clear();  
    Response.Buffer = true;  
    Response.ClearContent();  
    Response.ClearHeaders();  
    Response.Charset = "";  
    string FileName ="SomeFileName" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";  
    StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();  
    HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);        
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);  
    Response.ContentType ="application/vnd.ms-excel";    
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + FileName);
    allDataGridView.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    allDataGridView.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
    allDataGridView.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);  
    Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());  
    Response.End();      
}  
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
        server control at run time. */
}
```

The data within the gridview contains html formatting if that makes a difference. There are quite a few questions on exporting to excel but none for this particular issue.

EDIT: Gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="allDataGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="allDataDataSource" 
    ForeColor="#333333" Width="795px" Font-Size="X-Small">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CODE" HeaderText="Code" HtmlEncode="False" 
            SortExpression="CODE">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DESCRIPTION" HeaderText="Description" 
            HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="DESCRIPTION">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TAT" HeaderText="TAT" HtmlEncode="False" 
            SortExpression="TAT">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CONTACT" HeaderText="Contact" HtmlEncode="False" 
            SortExpression="CONTACT">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#005293" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

**UPDATE:** 
The HTML content in the gridview does seem to be the issue. When I set HTML Encode to False, the gridview exports correctly, albeit with HTML Tags. Any ideas on how to re-encode it after assigning the gridview data to the (htmltextwrtter)?

Comment: Can you post the markup of your gridview?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the HTML code in the gridview. It contained  and  tags, once those are removed, it exports fine.

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Demo.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

Label lblheader = new Label();
lblheader.Font.Size = new FontUnit(14, UnitType.Point);
lblheader.Font.Bold = true;
lblheader.Text = "Demo Details";
lblheader.RenderControl(hw);



GrdExcel.Visible = true;
GrdExcel.RenderControl(hw);

Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
GrdExcel.Visible = false;
```

**Use UpdatePanel and trigger.**

```
 <Triggers>
       <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnExcel" />
 </Triggers>
```

Comment: The same result was returned